# Pushing Updates To Application On Play Store With Dynamic Delivery

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, dynamic-delivery

I have an application on Play Store with dynamic delivery modules. I wanted to know if there was a better way of pushing updates via Play Store.

For example, I have two independent modules in my application. I need to push out an update which only affects one module and not the other one. Is there a way where we can only publish that single aab/apk to the Play Store without uploading the entire apk?

The reason for doing this is that I want my users to only receive the small update on one module, I don't want them to download the entire apk as an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to update only one module of the App Bundle, they are all updated atomically.

However, Play Store does some clever patching to minimize the bytes downloaded by users, so if some of those other modules remain unchanged, the actual downloaded size should be much smaller than the full APK.